# What does the Windows 10 defragmenter do if it encounters a bad sector in either the source or destination?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, defragment

What happens when defrag tries to read or write there? Does it error out and just stop? Does it warn the user of bad files? Does it try to fix anything? Does it keep going?

I know that if I suspect an issue with my HDD, I should run chkdsk before I do a defrag. I also know that Windows 10 schedules its own defrag ("disk optimization") and I don't have to do anything. I'm curious what might happen in this instance

Comment: " I should run chkdsk before I do a defrag." I always do.

Comment: Given that Windows 10 runs the defrag automatically, can you explain how you accomplish this?

Comment: You need to look at the Schedule in defragmenter setup and run CHKDSK before that. I added instructions for that to my answer

Comment: Disable auto defrag in task scheduler, then you can do it before manually defragging

Comment: Your question has a terminology issue.  With modern HDDs, software is not likely to encounter a *"bad sector"*, since bad block management is now (primarily) handled by the drive itself rather than the OS.  Logical block addressing (instead of CHS addressing) allows the drive to map out *"bad sectors'*.  Worst case would be a read request getting an uncorrectable error.

Answer (score 0):

As you point out Windows 10 Defrag is automatic and there is no need to manually run it.

Second, if you indeed suspect your hard drive, run CHKDSK to determine the extent of problem.

Then, if Windows actually tries to run Defrag on its own, it cannot move a damaged area on disk. So it will likely stop at that point because it cannot proceed.

I have not see that happen, but reads / writes generally cannot proceed over damaged areas (and I have seen that happen) so defrag would work the same way.

If you need to determine when Defrag will run, go to Admin Tools, Optimize and Defrag, and then use Change Settings at the bottom to look at or change the schedule.

Comment: NTFS file self healing in W10 works very well. NTFS self healing was introduced aggressively in Vista forward.>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-r2-and-2008/cc771388(v=ws.10)

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link

Comment: Thanks, John. My purpose for asking this question is not how to take care of the computer, but an analysis of the behavior of the defrag utility. Could you expand on what you have seen when reads / writes have been attempted on bad areas of the disk?

Comment: If the disk is good, there will not be errors. If the disk has bad areas on the disk, read / write will stall, retry, and either succeed by brute force, or fail, which is more likely. and if that fails, defrag will also likely hang up.

Answer (score 0):

The defragmenter doesn't do anything special. The same code handles the bad sector that would handle it in any other situation, say if the file was just being read or copied.

Assuming you're asking about NTFS on typical block devices, the process is complex. If there's redundancy (for example, if it's a RAID array) then the redundancy logic handles the situation. If it's a newly-assigned unit of space or a write operation to existing space, then the space is marked bad and a new one is assigned. If it's a read, the read can be retried and, if it succeeds, new space be allocated, the data moved, and the bad space marked bad.

The most interesting case is if all attempts to read fail and the space is in use. In that case, data can be lost. The last time I checked (twenty years ago or so), the data was moved to a newly-assigned unit of storage but the file data is lost, replaced with zeroes.

In the worst case, metadata such as directory information or space assignment information may be lost. In that case, an event will be reported requiring the file system to be repaired and lots of data could be lost.